# Graphic counter correction

Tags: javascript, graphics

I have a chart and my system that I need it to report the exact value of the search results.

Due to many data, the results come out so **1.1K**.

[image]

In the place that 1.1K wanted it shows the exact value that would be 1057.
Here is the graph function in JS:

```
function Post(url, param, title, totalText) {
    totalText = totalText || "Total";

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Graficos/" + url,
        data: param,
        beforeSend: function () {
            showLoader();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ChartConstructor(title, JSON.stringify(data), totalText);
        },
        complete: function () {
            hideLoader();
        }
    });
}

    function ChartConstructor(title, dados, totalText) {
        window.google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
        window.google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

        function drawStuff() {
            var table = JSON.parse(dados);
            var rows = "";

            var array = [["", "Total"]];

            for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                array.push([table[i].Title, table[i].Count]);
            }

            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

            var options = {
                width: '100%',
                height: 400,            
                chart: {
                    title: title,
                },
                bar: { groupWidth: '95%' },
                bars: 'horizontal',
                series: {
                    0: { axis: 'distance' }, 
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart-content"));
            chart.draw(data, options);

            $("#chart-type").val("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does ajax return full values?

Comment: I need the graph to return me the full value as you can see in the picture is coming 1.1K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#data-format), you can set the format of hAxis or vAxis to 'none' to display the full number.

Example:

```
        var options = {
            width: '100%',
            height: 400,            
            chart: {
                title: title,
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: '95%' },
            bars: 'horizontal',
            series: {
                0: { axis: 'distance' }, 
            },
            vAxis: {
                format: 'none'
            }
        };
```

Comment: I can not find this setting in my documentation

Comment: I never moved with graphics, could you give me another example?

Comment: Here's the full `options`, I think that should work, if not, replace vAxis with hAxis